# Is it true that the constant in the characteristic polynomial is $(-1)^n det A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

A is nxn matrix with the characteristic polynomial Pa(t).
Is it true that the constant in the characteristic polynomial is $(-1)^n det A$?

Please help me, I have a test tomorrow.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Think about the structure of polynomials...how is the constant term related to the roots?...

Comment: As you know the roots of characteristic polynomial are eigenvalues, it is sufficient that compute $p(0)$. In other hand, you can think about relation between product of eigenvalues and det(A).

Comment: Yes, test it yourself for a $2\times 2$-matrix. This will be on the test tomorrow (I guess).

Comment: @Babgen Overkill.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ is defined as the determinant of the matrix $\lambda I-A$, i.e. you change the signs of all elements of $A$ and then add *variable* $\lambda$ to all its diagonal elements. If $\lambda$ is considered variable, then the determinant is a function of this variable: plug in different values for $\lambda$, and you will get different matrices with different determinants. Now, what happens if you set $\lambda=0$? On one hand, you get matrix $-A$, on the other hand its determinant is the characteristic polynomial evaluated at $\lambda=0$.